# Resetting Python to system Python in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I've been trying to get `mysql-workbench` to work, and having a ton of issues.  Running it from terminal gives me the following:

```
File "/home/{My_username}/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 8, in <module>
from operator import _compare_digest as compare_digest
ImportError: cannot import name _compare_digest
Warning! Can't use connect with timeout in paramiko None
```

And when I try to connect via ssh to a database:

```
File "/home/{My_username}/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/2.7.12_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 36, in <module>
from paramiko import util
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

running `which python` gives me:

```
/home/{My_username}/.linuxbrew/bin/python
```

I would like to go back to the default `/usr/bin/python/`, but can not figure out what to change.  I think this is causing the `mysql-workbench` problems, or at least it will make it easier to solve them.  I've installed `paramiko` several times via `pip`, rebooted, and reinstalled `mysql-workbench`.  Yes, I'm new to Ubuntu, sorry.

Comment: As far as I know, you have to change the value in `PATH` variable which is in `etc/profile`

Comment: Yep, I had my PATH mixed up in ~/.profile. That cost me 3 hours of my life.  Tks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when I installed linuxbrew I had to add '/home/{username}/.linuxbrew/bin' to my PATH in '~/.profile' to get brew to work, but added it in front:

```
PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
```

This meant that the linuxbrew version of python became the default which causes lots of weird issues.  Changing the order around helped fix this:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin"
```

Now, the system default loads first, then linuxbrew stuff.  If you are a newb like me, you can edit this in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by using the following command:

```
sudo nano ~/.profile
```

Make your edits, hit `ctrl+o` `enter` then `ctrl+x` reboot the whole OS, and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm which python location is in use you can use:
 `which python`

To change the version per user:

```
 alias python='/usr/bin/python3.4'
```

Once you make the above change, re-login or source your .bashrc file:

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

Check your default python version:

```
$ python --version
```

To make you change system wide:

1. Log in as root
2. Find all alternatives

   **# update-alternatives --list python
   update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python**
3. If you get the above error, you need to update the alternatives:

   **# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 
   update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python2.7 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode**
   **# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.4 2
   update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3.4 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode**
4. check the version:

   **# python --version
   Python 3.4.2**
5. list again the alternatives:

   **# update-alternatives --list python
       /usr/bin/python2.7
       /usr/bin/python3.4**

You can update the alternatives anytime:

**`# update-alternatives --config python`**

Comment: I'm not looking to change the version, there is plenty of documentation on that.  I wanted to revert back to the system default Python after accidentally overwriting it in my PATH.